# How do I stop a parent DIV from stretching when I put an iFrame into it?

Tags: javascript, iframe, html

I won't post the code directly but you can see it here: http://markbrewerton.co.uk/work.html

I have links which load an iFrame into a DIV when they are clicked, however, as you will notice, the parent DIV is stretched and goes down really far. I'm pretty new to all this, so could you explain how I can fix it?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried fixing the height of the parent `<div>` by giving it a "height" style? Oh also "overflow: auto" maybe if you want the contents to scroll, though that may be better handled inside the iframe content.

Comment: Yeah, but that cuts off the bottom of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is the setup the bounds of the div by using the height and width styles.

After that set the overflow style.

Overflow has different values. Auto will likely get your the desired result. http://programming.top54u.com/post/HTML-Div-Tag-Overflow-CSS-Style-Scrollbars.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if you want scrollbars):

```
#yourdiv {
  height: 300px; /* fixed height */
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

...or this (if you want to just clip the content):

```
#yourdiv {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Edit: You can also fix the height of the `<iframe>` itself:

```
#youriframe {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This cuts of the bottom. Is there a way to get it to resize to the content in the iFrame?

Comment: @Mark, the contents of the iframe are simply filling it entirely -- just as if the iframe were a browser window. Try limiting the height of the iframe itself with something like `style="height: 400px;"`. Then the iframe contents will behave just as if they had been loaded into a small browser window.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you! You can see it here if you're interested:  http://markbrewerton.co.uk/work.html